# Toric degeneration of Kummer Surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, k3-surfaces, mirror-symmetry

I am wondering if there are any explicit examples of a toric degeneration of a Kummer surface (e.g. as a family of projective varieties say), and what the central fibre can look like? (I am working over $\mathbb{C}$).

For simplicity by toric degeneration I mean a degeneration to a union of toric varieties for now.

For example, a Kummer surface can be a blowup of a nodal quartic in $\mathbb{P}^3$ in 16 singular points. Is there a way I can degenerate the quartic to $4$ Hyperplanes and somehow extend this to a degeneration of the blowup?

The reason I ask this question is I am interested in seeing what the Gross-Siebert program tells us about mirrors of Kummer surfaces.

Comment: Maybe you can find this paper useful: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0209297

Comment: If we take the pencil of quartics $(wxyz)+t(w^4+x^4+y^4+z^4)$ (where $t$ is the parameter in the pencil), then this appears to be such a degeneration. By Bertini's theorem, (or in this case by direct calculation) the general element is smooth and so a K3 surface.

Comment: @Kapil I agree this gives a degeneration of K3s, but are any of the fibres Kummer surfaces?

Comment: The pencil $(1+12\lambda)xyzt + \lambda(4\lambda(x+y+z+t)^2 + (xy+xz+xt+yz+yt+zt))^2$ is a pencil of quartics with 16 nodes degenerating to four planes $xyzt=0$ when $\lambda=0$. The nodes are given by all 12 permutations of $(0:0:1:a)$ where $4\lambda(a+1)^2+a=0$ and all 4 permutations of $(b:1:1:1)$ where $4\lambda b + 12\lambda +1=0$, so the sixteen nodes go to the corners of the tetrahedron in four groups of four as $\lambda\to0$. You could try resolving the nodes in this family, but presumably this does something nontrivial to the corners of the tetrahedron in the fibre over $\lambda=0$.

Comment: @EvgenyT Sorry. I misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted K3 surfaces.